# A question in Dedekind cut

Tags: real-analysis

This is a proposition in my textbook：

**Let $\ x=A|B,x'=A'|B'$ be Dedekind cuts in Q. Define
$$x+x'=(A+A')|rest\ \ of\ \ Q $$
Then the union of A+A' and B+B' may not be Q.(Here we define $\ A+A'=\{y\ |\ \exists\ x \in A,\exists x' \in A',y=x+x'\} $)**

My question is under what circumstances are they not equal?

Comment: Adding two irrationals that add to a rational might have the union exclude the sum rational.  So $A = \{r\in Q| -r^2 < 2\}; B= \{r\in Q|-r^2 \ge 2\}$ and $A'=\{r\in Q|r^2 > 2\}$ and $B'= \{r\in Q|r\ge 2\}$ then $A+A'= \{r\in Q| r < 0\}$ and $B + B' = \{r\in Q|r > 0\}$ and the union doesn't include $0$.   See, there is no $q, q'$ pair were $q < -\sqrt 2$ and $q' > \sqrt 2$ where $q+q' = 0$

Comment: See related answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1264188/72031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding two irrationals that add to a rational might have the union exclude the sum rational.

For example $A= \{q\in \mathbb Q|q < 0, q^2 > r\}$ (essentially that $q< -\sqrt 2$) and $B= \{q\in \mathbb Q|q> a, \forall a\in A\}$.  While $A' = \{q\in \mathbb Q|$ either $q < 0$ and if $q \ge 0$ then $q^2 < 2\}$ (essentially that $q < \sqrt 2$) and $B= \{q\in \mathbb Q|q> a, \forall a \in A'\}$.

Then $A + A' = \{q\in \mathbb Q|q < 0\}$ while $B+B'=\{q\in \mathbb Q| q > 0\}$ and $(A+A')\cup (B+B') = \mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}$.

You can verify $0 \not \in A + A'$ as $q\in A+A'$ means $q = q_1 + q_2; q_1 < -\sqrt 2, q_2< \sqrt 2$ so $q=q_1 + q_2 < 0$.  And likewise $0 \not \in B+B'$ for the same reason.

======

The key to understanding Deidekind cuts (although this is cheating and putting the cart before the horse) is if $A|B\sim x$ for some $x \in \mathbb R$ (this is assuming we have *already* finally figured out what $\mathbb R$ is; and it was doing so that we *invented* the Deidekind cut in the first place--- so we *are* cheating when I say this; let me just be upfront about that ) .... Soif $A|B\sim x$ then $A = \{q\in \mathbb Q| q < x\}$ and $B=\{q\in \mathbb Q| q\ge x\}$.  And not that if $x$ is irrational than $B = \{q\in \mathbb Q| q > x\}$ as there is not rational $q=x$.

If we have a case where $x,y \not \in \mathbb Q$ but $x+y \in \mathbb Q$ then if we have $A|B\sim x$ and $A'|B\sim y$ then $A+B=\{q\in \mathbb|q=r+s, r< x, s<y\} = \{q\in \mathbb Q| q< x+y\}$

But we have $B+B' = \{q\in \mathbb Q| q\ge x\}+\{q\in \mathbb Q| q\ge r\}=\{q\in \mathbb Q| q> x\}+\{q\in \mathbb Q| q> x\}= \{q\in \mathbb Q|q=r+s; r> x, s> y\} = \{q\in \mathbb Q|q > x+y\}\ne \{q\in \mathbb Q|q\ge x+y\}$.

And so $(A+B)\cup (B+B') = \mathbb Q \setminus \{x+y\}$

Comment: thanks a lot. your answer also explains why we should not define x+x' as y ~ A+A'|B+B', because it may not be a cut.

Comment: I think I should add a bit about how a cut is defined. If we define a cut as only the lower $A$ part (which never has a highest element) and ignore the $B$ part (which may or may not have a lowest element [depending on whether we are cutting on a rational or between rationals) then we can define $x+x'$ as $A""=A+A'$. If we need $B,B'$ we can ... well, we can work something out. Like $B""=B+B'\cup\{\inf_{\mathbb Q}(B+B')\}$ (bearing in mind that $\{\inf_{\mathbb Q}(B+B')\}$ might be the empty set).